# Why the main method cant be loaded

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I would like to run the simple example mentioned below. Eclipse generates an error reading:

> main class can't be found or loaded

Please let me know how to fix this error and describe why it happens.

**Main.kt**

```
class Main {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Hello, World!")
    }       
}
```

Comment: You might want to specify a package. Try adding `package demo` to the top of your file. I do not use Eclipse, but if you need to type which class to search for `main`, then you should use `demo.MainKt` as the class name (Kotlin will rename the `Main` class to `MainKt`).

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that you don't need to declare a class in Kotlin, or even the Array param (if not needed): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/hello-world.html

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that the `main` function is not static.

To make it static, either put it out of the class (the recommended way):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Or use [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/index.html) annotation:

```
object Main {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Hello, World!")
    }       
}
```

Note that statics can only appear in objects. <strike>However, I am not sure that JVM will recognize such `main` method.</strike> It seems to be working as well:

[image]